# how to compare 12 consecutive rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, window-functions

In a `pandas.DataFrame`, I have a column `df['d_max']`. I want to compare 12 values at a time and if all 12 values are the same, then I need to flag it in the next column. currently, I have written the following code, and it's working fine. I wonder if there is any other better/more efficient way of doing the same. Please note, I am comparing the 12th value with previous 11 values in the column.

```
 # Check if the maximum value is repeated 12 times in succession  

 df['is_peak'] = ((df['d_max'].shift(-1) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-2) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-3) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-4) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-5) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-6) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-7) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-8) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-9) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-10) == df['d_max']) &
                     (df['d_max'].shift(-11) == df['d_max']))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example input (and ideally the matching expected output)

Comment: closed= 'left' is marking 13th element with 1. I need to mark the 12th element as 1. This solution by Sebastian Wozny is working for me with closed='right' in place of closed='left'. I am in the process of optimizing the code. When I replace my original code with this line, I Got the error message:  ValueError: closed only implemented for datetimelike and offset based windows.

Comment: Sorry to insist but can you provide the expected output, for example using Sebastian's `df = pd.DataFrame({'d_max': [2, 3] + [6] * 12 + [1, 5, 5, 5]})` input? Your code doesn't do what you describe, it uses the following rows not the previous ones.

Comment: OK, then not what your code is doing, you should use positive values in shift ;) I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Please add a full example of your data and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) to solve this, together with a window function. Window functions are available since `pandas` version 1.3.0 and are very well suited for looking at cumulations (e.g. cumsum,cumproduct,all-time-mean...) or for sliding window aggregations (mean of last `N` values).

```
df['is_peak'] = df['d_max'].rolling(12, closed='left').apply(lambda x:len(set(x))==1)
```

We need to supply `closed='left'` to make it exclude the current value of the window as it's being dragged over your data.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'d_max': [2, 3] + [6] * 12 + [1, 5, 5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['is_peak'] = df['d_max'][::-1].rolling(12, closed='left').apply(lambda x:len(set(x))==1)[::-1]
df
```

```
    d_max   is_peak
0   2   0.0
1   3   1.0
2   6   0.0
3   6   0.0
4   6   0.0
5   6   0.0
6   6   NaN
7   6   NaN
8   6   NaN
9   6   NaN
10  6   NaN
11  6   NaN
12  6   NaN
13  6   NaN
14  1   NaN
15  5   NaN
16  5   NaN
17  5   NaN
```

There is a performance difference between different approaches. Providing a custom lambda function in `apply` is incredibly slow compared to other approaches so we need to get creative to get something more performant than your original code.

If all values in a `Series` are equal, its variance is 0. We can apply this by using [`Rolling.var()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.var.html#pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.var):

```
df["d_max"].rolling(12, closed="left").var() == 0
```

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from performance_measurement import run_performance_comparison


def shift_approach(df):
    df["is_peak"] = (
        (df["d_max"].shift(1) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(2) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(3) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(4) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(5) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(6) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(7) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(8) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(9) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(10) == df["d_max"])
        & (df["d_max"].shift(11) == df["d_max"])
    )
    return df




def rolling_approach_var(df):
    df["is_peak"] = (
        df["d_max"].rolling(12, closed="left").var()==0
    )
    return df


def mozway_rolling_approach(df):
    df["is_peak"] = (
        df.rolling(12)["d_max"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].eq(x.iloc[-1]).all()).eq(1)
    )
    return df


from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv


def mozway_striding_approach(df):
    a = swv(df["d_max"], 12)
    df.loc[df.index[-len(a) :], "is_peak"] = (a[:, [0]] == a[:, 1:]).all(axis=1)
    return df


approaches = [
    rolling_approach_var,
    shift_approach,
    mozway_striding_approach,
]


def generate_data(dataset_size):
    """Generates some random data of size dataset size, while making sure some runs of 12 equal numbers are included"""
    data = {"d_max": np.random.randint(1, 10, dataset_size)}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    insert_indices = np.random.choice(
        range(dataset_size - 11), size=dataset_size // 12, replace=False
    )
    for idx in insert_indices:
        df.iloc[idx : idx + 12] = df.iloc[idx]

    return [df]


def generate_same_data(dataset_size):
    """Generates a dataframe where the series always has the same value"""
    data = {"d_max": [12] * dataset_size}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    return [df]


run_performance_comparison(
    approaches,
    [1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000,500000,1000000],
    setup=generate_same_data,
    title="Same data",
    number_of_repetitions=1,
)
```

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: N,
                               teardown=lambda: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5, title='Performance Comparison',data_name='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}

    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                approach_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: approach(*data), number=number_of_repetitions)
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Got error message:  ValueError: closed only implemented for datetimelike and offset based windows.

Comment: It executes fine in a python playground https://onecompiler.com/python/3ze7f2qjx . if it doesn't run in your specific example it would help if you post more of your code

Comment: As the efficiency doesn't get compromised, I would continue to use my original code. This taught me how to compare two code snippets.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the real dataset?

Comment: @SebastianWozny I recommend to use a log/log scale for better comparison ;)

Comment: around 150000 rows

Answer (score 2):

A modification of Sebastian's approach:

```
df['is_peak'] = df.rolling(12)['d_max'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].eq(x.iloc[-1]).all()).eq(1)
```

Or a numpy approach with [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

a = swv(df['d_max'], 12)

# df['is_peak'] = False # optional, if you don't want NaNs

df.loc[df.index[-len(a):], 'is_peak'] = (a[:, [0]] == a[:, 1:]).all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    d_max is_peak
0       2     NaN
1       3     NaN
2       6     NaN
3       6     NaN
4       6     NaN
5       6     NaN
6       6     NaN
7       6     NaN
8       6     NaN
9       6     NaN
10      6     NaN
11      6   False
12      6   False
13      6    True
14      1   False
15      5   False
16      5   False
17      5   False
```

Comparison of approaches:

Interestingly, numpy is faster until a few tens of thousands of rows, then slightly less efficient than shift, although the difference gets negligible for very large arrays.

[image]

edit: the difference is due to assignment. I also added Sebastian nice `var` trick:

[image]

Comment: When I started answering this question I did absolutely not expect the result that we got. Any clue what makes shift so performant here? The rolling probably suffers from all the `apply` invocations, but how does it get faster than strides? I thought maybe it was short circuting but it's also faster with data that just contains the same value.

Comment: @SebastianWozny I'm suspecting the assignment back to pandas to be the bottleneck. I'll wait that my timing is done and test that (I was too greedy, went up to 2**26 rows :p)

Comment: I found a faster solution than striding :D *happy noises*

Comment: @SebastianWozny it's indeed [assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8HWo.png) ;)

Comment: Can you supply function definitions? I'd really like to have all of them in one plot, including the new `var()` approach and see how that compares to numpy

Comment: @SebastianWozny sure, I added all in the same graph (but didn't recompute up to 67M rows, it's too long :p)